# How do I pull a xml data into html table using jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am working on `ASP.NET` project. There I want to pull a `xml` data into `html` table using jquery ? Here is the files,

employee.xml,

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <employeedetails>
    <Employee>
    <Name>"Indhu"</Name>
    <ID>"571367"</ID>
    <Designation>"Programmer Analyst"</Designation>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
    <Name>"Swetha"</Name>
    <ID>"568877"</ID>
    <Designation>"Analyst"</Designation>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
    <Name>"Vibisha"</Name>
    <ID>"568879"</ID>
    <Designation>"Senior Analyst"</Designation>
    </Employee>
    </employeedetails>
```

script_tbemployeedetails.js,

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
type:'GET',
url:'employee.xml',
dataType:'xml',
success:function(xmlData){
$("Employee",xmlData).each(function(){
String name=$(this).find("Name").text(),
String id=$(this).find("ID").text(),
String designation=$(this).find("Designation").text();
$(tb_employee).append('<tr>');
$(tb_employee).append('<td>'+name+'</td>');
$(tb_employee).append('<td>'+id+'</td>');
$(tb_employee).append('<td>'+designation+'</td>');
$(tb_employee).append('<tr>');
});
)}
});
}
```

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="EmployeeDetails_XML._Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
<title>Extract and Read XML Data Using jQuery and Ajax</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<table id="tb_employee">
<tr>
<th>NAME</th>
<th>ID</th>
<th>DESIGNATION</th>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server" DataFile="~/employee.xml">
</asp:XmlDataSource>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my code. I could not pull `xml` data into `html` table. How can I do this ?

Please help me...

Comment: You are not using the correct selector `$(tb_employee)` should be `$('#tb_employee')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
$(tb_employee).append('<tr>');
$(tb_employee).append('<td>'+name+'</td>');
$(tb_employee).append('<td>'+id+'</td>');
$(tb_employee).append('<td>'+designation+'</td>');
$(tb_employee).append('<tr>');
```

A way to create and append a new row is:

```
$(tb_employee).append(
     $('<tr/>').append($('<td/>', {text: name}))
        .append($('<td/>', {text: id}))
        .append($('<td/>', {text: designation}))
);
```

```js
var xmlStr ='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>\
          <employeedetails>\
          <Employee>\
          <Name>"Indhu"</Name>\
          <ID>"571367"</ID>\
          <Designation>"Programmer Analyst"</Designation>\
          </Employee>\
          <Employee>\
          <Name>"Swetha"</Name>\
          <ID>"568877"</ID>\
          <Designation>"Analyst"</Designation>\
          </Employee>\
          <Employee>\
          <Name>"Vibisha"</Name>\
          <ID>"568879"</ID>\
          <Designation>"Senior Analyst"</Designation>\
          </Employee>\
          </employeedetails>';
  var xmlData = $.parseXML(xmlStr);
  /*
  $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '1.xml',
      dataType: 'xml',
      success: function (xmlData) {
      *****/
          $("Employee", xmlData).each(function () {
              var name = $(this).find("Name").text();
              var id = $(this).find("ID").text();
              var designation = $(this).find("Designation").text();
              $(tb_employee).append(
                      $('<tr/>').append($('<td/>', {text: name}))
                              .append($('<td/>', {text: id}))
                              .append($('<td/>', {text: designation}))
              );
          });
      //}
  //});
```

```css
table {
    width:100%;
}
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table id="tb_employee">
    <tr>
        <th>NAME</th>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>DESIGNATION</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```